# Making a Circular SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, supportmapfragment

On Android API 28, using Kotlin, I'm trying to make my `SupportMapFragment` circular so I can make it have animation around it, however, when I try to turn `clipToOutline` to true, it still stays a square. How can I conform this into a circle? Thank you!

**// Preview of Screenshot**

[image]

**// XML**

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/customerMapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_mask"
    android:clipToOutline="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/customer_map_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/pulsatingCircle"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/pulsatingCircle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/pulsatingCircle" />
```

**// circle_mask**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="300dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**// Kotlin Code**

```
private fun initMap() {
    val mapView = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.customerMapView) as SupportMapFragment

    mapView.view?.outlineProvider = ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND
    mapView.view?.clipToOutline = true
}
```

I tried setting `clipToOutline` to true in the xml and Kotlin files, but in the xml, I need to be on API 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CardView for that.

As you have fixed width and height, you can pass a specific corner radius to make it look like circle and you're done!

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/mapCardLayout"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/customerMapView"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**If you don't have a specific width or height, then you can go with the custom view with the same width height for proper circle like this,**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView

class CircleCardView : MaterialCardView {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec)
    }
}
```

**For circle appearance, make a custom style attribute and use it with the cardview like this,**

In the `style.xml`,

```
<style name="CustomCardCornerStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay_card_corners</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay_card_corners" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>
```

In your `layout.xml`,

```
<com.demo.motiondemo.CircleCardView
        android:id="@+id/mapCardLayout"
        style="@style/CustomCardCornerStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/customerMapView"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.demo.motiondemo.CircleCardView>
```